# Edit Netbeans Template for "Test for Existing Class"

Tags: java, templates, netbeans, code-generation, netbeans-7.3

Changing the code that Netbeans generates is usually pretty easy, you just edit the associated template. However, there doesn't appear to be one for "Test For Existing Class".

[image: Netbeans unit test templates]

Is there something different I have to do, or is the template just somewhere else or what?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by modification of existing "Test Class - JUnit 4.x" item. You can save original template by duplicating it.